# No error logging when dead letter queue enabled

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

Whenever there is an error while processing incoming messages the failed messages are moved to the Dead letter queue.
However, the exception that caused the message is not logged.

spring cloud stream : 4.0.1

Binder : Kafka

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
       definition: preProcessingMessageAudit|abcProcessing|postProcessingMessageAudit
    stream:
     function:
        bindings:
             preProcessingMessageAudit|abcProcessing|postProcessingMessageAudit-in-0: input
             preProcessingMessageAudit|abcProcessing|postProcessingMessageAudit-out-0: output
     bindings:
        input:
           destination: ABCIncomingChannel
           consumer:
            concurrency: 4
           group: mpa
        output:
           destination: ABCOutgoingChannel
           producer:
            partitionCount: 4
     kafka:
        binder:
          kafka-properties:
            bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
          replicationFactor : 1 
          autoAddPartitions : true
        bindings:
           input:
             consumer:
                enableDlq: true
                dlqName: abc-dead-letter
```

Comment: Can you please provide more information, relevant configuration etc. I am trying to understand why do you expect the error to be logged if you chose DLQ as an error handling mechanism?

Comment: 1.  tool  monitors the log continuously and if there is any error written in the log  immediately raises an alarm and email alerts would be triggered      
2. If error is logged into log file and helps operational team to ship log file to app team for analysis
Can we enable error logging to log file and publish to  DLQ please ?

Comment: Agreed. Can you please raise an issue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues

Comment: Thanks .Done 
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2672